# innerHTML muestra [object HTMLLIElement] en vez de añadir un <li>

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo...

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li>Muestra 1</li>
    <li>Muestra 2</li>
    <li>Muestra 3</li>
    <li>Muestra 4</li>
    <li>Muestra 5</li>
    <li>Muestra 6</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="promptTexto()">Clic aquí</button>
```

**JS**

```
function promptTexto(){
    var texto = document.createTextNode(prompt("Texto: "));
    var nuevoLi = document.createElement("li");
    nuevoLi.appendChild(texto);
    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].innerHTML += nuevoLi;
}
```

Lo que quiero és que puedas añadir un elemento `<li>` al clicar el botón. En cambio, en vez de añadir un `<li>`, pone `[object HTMLLIElement]`. He probado poniendo `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].innerHTML += nuevoLi.textContent;` pero sólo me añade el texto, sin la etiqueta `<li>`.

No he podido encontrar nada y llevo un buen rato buscando. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, yo te aporto una la cual creo que es de las más sencillas.

Primero añade un **id** a tu **ul** en tu archivo **.html**:

```
  <ul id="MiLista">
    <li>Muestra 1</li>
    <li>Muestra 2</li>
    <li>Muestra 3</li>
    <li>Muestra 4</li>
    <li>Muestra 5</li>
    <li>Muestra 6</li>
  </ul>
```

Y en el archivo **.js**:

```
function promptTexto(){
  var nuevoLi = document.createElement("LI");
  var texto = document.createTextNode(prompt("Texto: "));;
  nuevoLi.appendChild(texto);
  document.getElementById("MiLista").appendChild(nuevoLi);
}
```

Llama a tu función de tal forma que cree el elemento **li**, pregunte por el texto, asigne el texto al **li** y lo inserte en el elemento con id "*MiLista*", el cual en este caso, hace referencia a tu **ul**.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo del funcionamiento: [Ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qfYfNCEUkUA7IjhB?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

Cualquier duda no dudes en comentármela.

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, gracias :p

Comment: De nada! A ti :)